# Can't pass a var to an other activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem to pass a var to an other activity:
This is where I take the variable:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scelta);               
    // l'intent di questa activity
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String pkg = getPackageName();
    //prendiamo i dati         
    nome=intent.getStringExtra(pkg+".myNome");
```

This is where I change activity:

```
public void checkout (View v){
    // l'intent di questa activity
    Intent intent;
    String pkg=getPackageName();
    intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), checkout.class);
    //li reinseriamo nell'intent
    intent.putExtra(pkg+".myNome", nome);
    intent.putExtra(pkg+".myId", id);

    Log.d(TAG,"questo è il nome che va ad instargh:"+nome);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

thanks to log I am certain that "nome" have the value that i want.
This is where i take "myNome"

```
public class checkout<targhe> extends ListActivity
{String sId=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checkout); 
    Intent intent;
    String pkg=getPackageName();                    
    intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), scelta.class);
    nome=intent.getStringExtra(pkg+".myNome");
    Log.D(TAG,"name"+nome);}
```

with this Log "nome" is always null. I don't understand why I can't take myNome from the intent :/

this is not all the code,but the parts the is important for my problem.

Some one can help me?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the answer, but tell me really, do you have a requirement to use non English naming of your variables or is this your personal desire?

Answer (score 4):

Carefully see your code

in checkout Activity you have written

```
nome=intent.getStringExtra(pkg+".myNome");
```

Replace above line of code with following

```
nome=getIntent().getStringExtra(pkg+".myNome");
```

Comment: Thanks :) now function all :D

Comment: If it solve your problem you should close it by accepting it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `checkout`, try changing

```
Intent intent;                  
intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), scelta.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

And see if that works.

Also, are both of your `Activity`s in the same package? If not, `getPackageName()` will be different in both.

Answer (score 0):

You should use getIntent().getStringExtra(pkg+".myNome");